# copy a selected text to clipboard using a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to write a Chrome extension, to easy copy a selected text, then simulate a F12 keypress.. I don't know how I do it.... any idea?

```
var contexts = ["selection"];
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
var context = contexts[i];
var title = "Retrieve '%s' in MyProgram";
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                   "onclick": genericOnClick});

console.log("'" + context + "' item:" + id);
}
```

the selected text I have in '%s' but I don't know how I copy to clipboard... and then will be good to send a F12 keypress to the windows system...